# Android windowInsets.getStableInsetBottom got deprecated in Android 11. What's the alternative for it?

Tags: android

I'm using materrialShowcaseView library in that `hasNavBar()` method having `windowInsets.getStableInsetBottom` deprecated method as below.

```
private boolean hasNavBar() {
    boolean tempHidden = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE;
    if (tempHidden)
        return false;
    View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        WindowInsets windowInsets = decorView.getRootWindowInsets();
        if (windowInsets != null) {
            return windowInsets.getStableInsetBottom() != 0;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets#getStableInsetBottom()) you can use following method to solve the deprecated method:

```
windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars()).bottom
```

Comment: This only works API 30+ since Type.systemBars() was added in API+

Answer (score 0):

The **complete** Solution I have reached.

```
            when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R -> {
                view.rootWindowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars()).bottom
            }
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M -> {
                view.rootWindowInsets?.stableInsetTop ?: 0
            }
            else -> {
                0
            }
        }
```